# Getting access to remote machines through remote server behind the NAT

Tags: linux, vpn, nat, tunneling

I want to have access to remote machines that connected to remote server behind the nat (actually it's just another computer with linux). [Here you can see scheme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6u5.png)

I'm using logmein hamachi to create connection between local machine and remote server and then sshuttle to tunnel traffic. But after few minutes of using sshuttle hamachi terminates connection and I need to restart its service. Hamachi works fine if I not using sshuttle.

My sshuttle command: `sshuttle -r username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -x xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 0/0 -vv`

Maybe there is another way to share network through nat?

I need to get access to sites, services, machines that belongs to servers local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't want to do this, but I created *OpenVPN* server on remote server and share local network to clients. And it's seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding will be your best bet to achieve this.

On the NAT device, presumably a router, you will have the option to add a port forwarding rule. You will need to check how this is done exactly for your case.

It is advised that you use custom port for SSH, e.g. not 22 in order to connect. The port forwarding will forward requests from the said custom port to a local address and port behind the NAT. In other works it will look like this:

Connection to externalIp:CustomPort will forward traffic to internalIp:22

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change router settings, so I use hamachi to get direct access to remote server.

Comment: And to get connection to services behind the NAT on other machines, I used tunneling traffic or VPN. Also I tried to create SOCKS proxy by SSH through Hamachi, but it terminates connection as like using sshuttle.